# Prisma OrderBy Coalesc

Tags: javascript, prisma

I have a Problem using Prisma where I want to findMany with a specific order.

My Model looks like this

```
model Item {
    id            Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
    title         String
    categoryId      Int
    category        Category          @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
}

model Category {
    id            Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
    title         String
    parentId      Int?
    parent        Category?  @relation("categoryRelation", fields: [parentId], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
    subCategories Category[] @relation("categoryRelation")
    items         Item[]
}
```

now I want to sort my items by category.parentId but if they dont have a parentId, I want to sort by categoryId. In raw sql I could use something like `orderBy coalesce(c.parentId, categoryId)`
but I would like to use the prisma way to solve this if there is one

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Prisma doesn't support `COALESCE` in any shape or form.

For some use-cases you can potentially have multiple `AND`s and/or `OR`s to achieve certain results, however I don't think you can actually coalesce to a single column name that can then be sorted.